FlatList not preserving changed state of an individual item of the list
I've a quiz app where user can select an answer from four options. The problem is when the user selects the answer of a particular question (say Q.115 being answered option 2) and then moves on to answer next questions, and then goes back to the previously answered question by scrolling top, the question shows UNANSWERED (Q.115 is not answered anymore even though the user has selected an answer/changed the state). The total list is of 200 items.
<FlatList
  data={data}
  ref={flatListRef}
  initialNumToRender={25}
  maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
  ListHeaderComponent={<HeaderComponent time_array={time_array} />}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <EachQuestionItem
    question_number={item.key}
    question={item.question}
    option_one={item.option_one}
    option_two={item.option_two}
    option_three={item.option_three}
    option_four={item.option_four}
    correct_option={item.correct_option}
  />}
  keyExtractor={item => item.key}
/>

The EachQuestionItem contains:
/* State to store marked option. 1 2 3 4 */
    const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState();

<RadioGroup 
  radioButtons={radioButtons} 
  onPress={setSelectedId}
  containerStyle={styles.optionContainer}
  labelStyle={{
    ...styles.optionText,
    color: colorScheme === 'dark' ? '#fafafa90' : '#00000090'
  }}
  selectedId={selectedId}
/>

Here selectedId is the state that gets changed, but that data is not saved/preserved by FlatList which is the problem.
Have tried to render the whole set of 200 questions (initialNumToRender={200}) at once but it was too slow to render, and so not an option. Also the state change is getting expensive/less responsive, have to touch twice/thrice to change the state/mark an answer.

The following topic can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676491/react-native-flatlist-with-individual-state-for-every-component

@blimatech thanks for the link you shared but I'm already using a different component for renderItem i.e EachQuestionItem which has it's own state. The problem, that is the state change is not reflected properly in FlatList still exists. Please let me know if you've got a solution.
